# Check series for convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \sin(n)\sin\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{1/4}}\right) $$
I have no idea how to deal with it.

Comment: If I may ask: where did you encounter such a problem?

Comment: Failed to solve it at analysys classes in the University

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\sin(n)\sin\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{1/4}}\right)=(-1)^n\sin(n)\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^{1/4}}\right)$$

Now, show that there exists a number $M$ (added hint:  $M=\sec(1/2)$ suffices) such that for all $N$

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n\sin(n)\right|\le M$$

Finally, apply [Dirichlet's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test#Statement) noting that $\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^{1/4}}\right)>0$ and monotonically decreases to zero.

**SPOILER ALERT:**  Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution

> Note that we have $$\begin{align}\left|\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n\sin(n)\right|&=\left|\text{Im}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N (e^{i(1+\pi)})^n\right)\right|\\\\&=\left|\text{Im}\left(\frac{e^{i(1+\pi)} -(e^{i(1+\pi)})^{N+1}}{1-e^{i(1+\pi)}}\right)\right|\\\\&=\left|\frac{\sin\left(\frac{(1+\pi)N}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{(1+\pi)(N+1)}{2}\right)}{\cos(1/2)}\right|\\\\ &\le \sec(1/2)\end{align}$$

Comment: Are you sure that you have read the problem correctly?

Comment: How did you extract $n^{1/4}$ from sin ?

Comment: @arsonist I've edited accordingly.  All carries through.  ;-))

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla What alternating series test.  Leibniz's test requires $a_n\ge 0$.  $\sin(n)$ does not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: Okey, and what should I do if the problem is just the same, but the exponent of (-1) is n(n+1)(n+2)/6?

Comment: @arsonist Note that with the new exponent, only every fourth term is $-1$.  But, one can still find a uniform $M$ and hence Dirichlet's Test still applies.

Comment: 1/sin is csc no?

Comment: @KitterCatter It is $1/\cos(1/2) = \sec(1/2)$.  Thank you for the catch.  -Mark

Comment: I think this catches -1 to any power since that is just rearranging the $ \pi$s. Still got a be less than csc(1/2)